# How to add style after web component stable state?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, web-component

I have a parent component, it generates another 60 child component on render. after the render completed, and my parent component added with body, I would like to adjust the margin, paddings. because i require the length of child components.

when i try now getting output as 'null' any one help me please?

here is my code :

```
import './../components/avatar.component';
import RandomEmails from './../services/random-email-service';

export default class AvatarContainer extends HTMLElement {

    shadowObj;
    imageProps = [];
    imageURL = `http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/6288f2a2679a0242771aa6cc02e85980?d=identicon&s=200`;

    constructor(){
        super();
        this.shadowObj = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
    }

    connectedCallback() {
       this.imageProps = RandomEmails();
       this.render();
       this.setStyleByRequired();
    }

    render() {

        let rows = this.imageProps.map((data,index) => {
            return this.getTemplate(data);
        });

        this.shadowObj.innerHTML = `<div class="avatars-holder">${rows.join('')}</div>`;
        //how to call after completion of this?

    }

    getTemplate(data) {
        return(
            `
            <avatar-block link="${data.link}" email="${data.email}"></avatar-block>
            ${this.getStyle()}
            `
        )
    }

    setStyleByRequired() {
        console.log('set now', document.querySelector('.avatars-holder')) //getting null
    }

    getStyle() {
        return(
            `
        <style>
            .avatars-holder {
                display:flex;
                flex-direction:row;
                flex-wrap: wrap;
                overflow:auto;
                height:100%;
            }
        </style>
        `
        )
    }

}

customElements.define('avatar-container', AvatarContainer);
```

Answer (score 1):

`connectedCallback` does not guarantee the element (and thus, its children) has been parsed. If you need guaranteed child access, add your webcomponent bundle like this:

```
<script src="/path/to/bundle.js" defer></script>
```

`defer` makes sure your bundle is not executed before `DOMContentLoaded` occurs, and delays the end of that event until after the bundle has been executed (all of the synchronous code). This forces the upgrade process to be applied to your webcomponents, at a point in time when the browser guarantees that alll the elements in the DOM have been parsed.

Alternatively, use `HTMLParsedElement` (which I helped create), which addresses specifically this problem.

> https://github.com/WebReflection/html-parsed-element

As a sidenote:

```
this.shadowObj = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
```

is unnecessary,

```
this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
```

is sufficient and the shadow root is accessible in

```
this.shadowRoot
```

automatically.

Comment: I am using webpack. any idea to add `defer` - thanks in advance

Comment: now my js file look like this: `<script type="text/javascript" src="bundle.min.js" defer></script></body>` -but getting the same output. any help please?

Answer (score 0):

it works fine for me:

`const avatarHolder = this.shadowObj.querySelector('.avatars-holder');`

thanks.

Comment: It might work now, but like Connexo says, ``connectedCallback`` does not **guarantee** all DOM elements are parsed. Another workaround is to add a 0 milliseconds ``setTimeout`` to make sure the Event loop has finished